# Is it possible to pass id to controller from dynamically appended html?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I wrote some js which append html with specific id:

```
document.querySelector("#period").addEventListener("change", function () {

    var selectedOptionValue = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
    var closestElement = this.closest('th');

   
    if (selectedOptionValue == 'Invoices') {

        $("<div id='date1'>Date from: <input class='form-control datepicker' id='dateFrom' name='dateFrom' type='date' value=''></div>").appendTo(closestElement);
        $("<div id='date2'>Date to: <input class='form-control datepicker' id='dateTo' name='dateTo' type='date' value=''></div>").appendTo(closestElement);

    } else {

        var dateFrom = document.querySelector('#date1');
        var dateTo = document.querySelector('#date2');
        dateFrom.remove();
        dateTo.remove();
    }
});
```

I try to pass id (dateFrom, dateTo) from this dnamically appended html to controller (I initialize those parameters with null value when page starts):

```
 public ActionResult XYZ(DateTime? dateFrom = null, DateTime? dateTo = null) ...
```

Unfortunately null values are always passed. Is it possible at all to pass id to controller from dynamically inserted html?

**EDIT:**  below I add View code, where I show how I submit id to Controller:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("XYZ", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
        {
            <th>
                @Html.DropDownList("period", new List<SelectListItem>
               {
                    new SelectListItem { Text="Today", Value="Today"},
                    new SelectListItem { Text="LastMonth",Value="LastMonth"}, "Choose period"})

                <button type="submit" class="szukaj"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
</th>
//...more code here
```

I append date inputs to  so I submit their ids to controller. Or maybe I'm doing sth wrong?

Comment: At the point of submission, it doesn't matter if the HTML code was added dynamically. The question is, what method you use to pass that value to the controller?

Comment: ok I added some View code, please take a look.

Comment: Instead of adding/removing these fields, why not create them normally using HTML helpers (as you did with the dropdown list) and just make them hidden, and then show/hide them as needed? Would need less code, and be more maintainable. And might have less trouble with binding too